# Rotating only MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation, presentmodalviewcontroller

I want to rotate only `MFMailComposeViewController` based on the device orientation, but not the `root view controller`. Basically I want to do it just like in Apple's app Voice Memos, the whole app does not support orientation but the `MFMailComposeViewController` does. Is this possible, or should I rotate manually the `MFMailComposeViewController`?